# How to avoid stretching the equation in multline mode when the width is defined?

Tags: equations, mathtools, multline

I would like to achieve:

- the multline equation spans horizontally `.7\textwidth`
- the first line is aligned to the left side
- the second line is aligned to the right side

So far I have:

[image]

Could you explain me how to fix the problem of stretching the equations?

Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[2]

\begin{equation}
  \begin{multlined}[.7\textwidth]
    \shoveleft{a = b + }\\
    \shoveright{+ c}
  \end{multlined}
\end{equation}

\lipsum*[2]

\end{document}
```

The closest [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58149/how-do-i-obtain-multline-type-alignment-within-a-group-of-equations?rq=1) that I found does not have this problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just don't want to use `\shoveleft` and `\shoveright`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[2]
\begin{equation}
  \begin{multlined}[.7\textwidth]
  a = b +{}\\
  {}+c
  \end{multlined}
\end{equation}
\lipsum*[2]

\end{document}
```

The empty atoms `{}` are needed for getting the right spacing.

[image]

Comment: Then what is a use case of using `shoveleft` and `shoveright`? From the documentation I was sure it is made for such things.

Comment: @desa The documentation is quite unclear indeed.

Comment: @desa - `\shoveleft` and `\shoveright` start to become useful once the `multline` and `multlined` environments contain three or more rows.